# unable to connect to socket in android getting timed out

Tags: android, sockets, android-networking

Hi I want to connect to server on a local network and I using socket for this. I am doing the socket connect part in Asyntask doinBackground. But I am getting timedout. please see the below code.

```
@Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            mSocket = new Socket(arg0[0], Integer.valueOf(arg0[1]));
            return 1;
        } catch ( IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Following is the logs captured :

```
10-03 18:24:39.025: W/System.err(15775): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to         
/192.168.11.125 (port 50000): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
10-03 18:24:39.026: W/System.err(15775):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
10-03 18:24:39.028: W/System.err(15775):    at    
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
10-03 18:24:39.029: W/System.err(15775):    at    
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
10-03 18:24:39.031: W/System.err(15775):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
10-03 18:24:39.033: W/System.err(15775):    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
10-03 18:24:39.034: W/System.err(15775):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
10-03 18:24:39.036: W/System.err(15775):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
10-03 18:24:39.037: W/System.err(15775):    at   
com.SDI.hrsimulator.MainActivity$SocketHelper.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:273)
10-03 18:24:39.039: W/System.err(15775):    at 
com.SDI.hrsimulator.MainActivity$SocketHelper.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-03 18:24:39.040: W/System.err(15775):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-03 18:24:39.041: W/System.err(15775):    at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-03 18:24:39.043: W/System.err(15775):    at 
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-03 18:24:39.044: W/System.err(15775):    at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-03 18:24:39.046: W/System.err(15775):    at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-03 18:24:39.047: W/System.err(15775):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-03 18:24:39.049: W/System.err(15775): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: 
ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
10-03 18:24:39.053: W/System.err(15775):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
10-03 18:24:39.054: W/System.err(15775):    at    
libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
10-03 18:24:39.055: W/System.err(15775):    at   
libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
10-03 18:24:39.056: W/System.err(15775):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
10-03 18:24:39.057: W/System.err(15775):    ... 14 more
```

arg[0] = ip address = "192.168.11.25" arg[1] = port number 50000

Comment: You think it is not important that we know the contents of arg0[0] and [1] ? Please post the log in a codeblock too so it does not wrap.

Comment: You could switch off the firewall.

Comment: @greenapps arg[0] = ip address = "192.168.11.25" arg[1] = port number 50000   I have edited the logs so that its placed in code block.